# How to set font horizontal scale on itext7

Tags: c#, itext7

I have using c# itext 7 (7.2.5) for create a pdf document.
I need modify the font characteristics.

My code:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.SetPadding(0);
p.SetMargin(0);
var style = new Style();
style.SetFont(Fonts.GetFont(font));
style.SetFontColor(Colors.BIANCO);
style.SetFontSize(maxFontSize);
style.SetCharacterSpacing(-2.5F);           
style.SetWordSpacing()

var content = new Text(text);
content.AddStyle(style);

p.SetFont(Fonts.GetFont(font));
p.SetFontColor(Colors.BIANCO);
p.SetFontSize(maxFontSize);

            
p.SetFixedLeading(height);
p.SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
p.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);
            
p.Add(content);
```

But I not find how to set horizontal scale of fonts.

Thanks